# What's the maximum life for mec troopers?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/MEC

Says that a paladin should have 36 hits. That should be added to the 4 hit points of the troop itself. So total there should be like 40 hit points.

My mec have 27 hitpoints at most.

Enemy within.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the wiki article you provided :

> A MEC or Mechanized Exoskeletal Cybersuit (aka MEC Suit) is a specialized combat rig utilized by a MEC Trooper.
>
> Each of the tiers has a different name, bonus stats and a different selection of Tactical Subsystems; **Tactical Subsystems stack with those from previous tiers** for a total of three available on any given MEC.

Only subsystems stack, not stats bonuses ; hence, a MEC Trooper equipped with a Paladin will have the following stats bonuses :

> +16 Armor Health, +10 Defense, +20 Will

Your 27 HP MEC Troopers have 9 HP + 16 armor, which is the maximum they can achieve at Colonal Rank. (see the [wiki page for Stat Growth](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Stat_Growth#Colonel_Stats))